# Averaging salary by location across two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

There are two tables, one with the employees salary and another with the department.
table1:

```
employee_id       name         salary
--------------------------------------
01                K.Irving     30000
02                J.Polk       50000
03                S.Smith      20000
04                D.Rai        35000
```

table2:

```
employee_id       name         department
------------------------------------------
01                K.Irving     marketing
02                J.Polk       finance
03                S.Smith      marketing
04                D.Rai        it
```

I would like to find out how to find the average salary per department where it is lower than 40000

Ideally it should look like this:

```
avg_salary         department
-----------------------------
35000              it
25000              marketing
```

So far I have tried to combine the two tables using the following formula, however I am having trouble putting in the conditions I wanted:

```
SELECT table1.employee_id
     , table1.name
     , table1.salary
     , table2.department
  FROM table1 
  LEFT 
  JOIN table2
    ON table1.employee_id = table2.employee_id 
   AND table1.employee_name = table2.employee_name
 ORDER 
    BY salary DESC;
```

The solution would be a mixture of the above and below, I was not sure how to combine the two.

```
SELECT AVG(salary), department
FROM table1, table2
GROUP BY department
HAVING AVG(salary) <40000
ORDER BY salary DESC;
```

I was not sure how to get the averages per department, when I used the code above it took an average of all salaries.

Comment: Hints: Use `AVG()` to calculate an average, `GROUP BY` to specify how the averages should be calculated, and `HAVING` to filter the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `GROUP BY` the department and limit the results with a `HAVING` clause.

```
SELECT avg(e.salary) avg_salary,
       d.department
       FROM table2 d
            LEFT JOIN table2 e
                      ON e.employee_id = d.employee_id
       GROUP BY d.department
       HAVING avg(e.salary) < 4000
       ORDER BY e.salary DESC;
```

But note, that your design is bad. There should be a table for the departments, that only stores the departments, not any employees to it. Then there should be a linking table with just a user and a department ID to store which employees is in which department. There should not be the employee (or the department) name in that table.

Comment: good answer, there are more problems than that with the design though. There should also be an employee table...

Answer (score 0):

A `LEFT JOIN` is unnecessary for this problem.  In order for the average to be well-defined, you need to have matches between the tables.  Hence:

```
SELECT avg(e.salary) as avg_salary,
       d.department
FROM table2 d JOIN 
     table2 e
     ON e.employee_id = d.employee_id
GROUP BY d.department
HAVING avg_salary < 4000
ORDER BY e.salary DESC;
```

As a convenience, you can also use the column alias in the `HAVING` clause.